# How to wrap a tikzpicture?

Tags: latex, word-wrap, tikz

```
       \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1,>=stealth]
                \coordinate (O) at (-0.3, -0.2);
                \coordinate (Y) at (-0.2, 4);
                \coordinate (X) at (4, -0.2);
                \coordinate (A) at (2.8, 2.2);
                \coordinate (XA) at (-0.3, 2);
                \coordinate (YA) at (2.5, -0.3);
                \node at (O) {$O$};
                \node at (A) {$A$};
                \node at (XA) {$x_{A}$};
                \node at (YA) {$y_{A}$};
                \draw[fill=black] (2.5, 2) circle(1.5pt);
                \draw[fill=black] (0, 0) circle(1.5pt);
                \draw[fill=black] (0, 2) circle(1.5pt);
                \draw[fill=black] (2.5, 0) circle(1.5pt);
                \node at (Y) {\large{$y$}};
                \node at (X) {\large{$x$}};
                \draw[-latex] [ultra thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 4);
                \draw[-latex] [ultra thick] (0, 0) -- (4, 0);
                \draw[dashed] (2.5, 2) -- (0, 2);
                \draw[dashed] (2.5, 2) -- (2.5, 0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        *text will be here*
```

I want to make text wrapping for this graph built using "tikz", but the method with "wrapfigure" does not help

i tried to use "wrapfigure"